# Start Visual Studio - Net Framework 4.6 not installed - Windows 10

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have tried everything from suggested questions .

I am getting "NET Framework 4.6 not installed", when I try to start Visual Studio 2017 or/and remove apps, which depends on it, like Visual Studio 2019.

I am using Windows 10.

I have tried everything, except reinstalling Windows 10, including:

- `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` with success.

Turn off/on features (Framework 4.8) for Windows 10.

If I try to install another NET Framework (for the example NET 4.6.2), it says:

`.NET Framework 4.6.2 or a later update is already installed on this computer.`

This is the error from XML file:

> ```
> <record>26</record>
> <time>2020/01/25 18:04:39.727</time>
> <type>Error</type>
> <source>VisualStudio</source>
> <description>Failure calling IsCompatibleNDPVersionInstalled.</description>
> <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
> <errorinfo></errorinfo>
> ```

From NET Framework repair tool:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/106459/cant-installuse-vs-2017.html

Comment: I have no "NETFramework setup" in the registry. I have `NETFramework` with `NGenQueue`.

Comment: Well, that's why.  Having your registry turn into silly-putty is rather a problem, such mishaps are rarely isolated.  You could give [this tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2698555/microsoft-net-framework-repair-tool-is-available) a spin.

Comment: Thanks, but this1 was used couple of times. I will use it again to show the final result

Comment: You can check the question.

Comment: I have similar problem. When I change `version` it shows more errors in log file.

Comment: Here are my logs https://rentry.co/ebxzg

Answer (score 3):

The way you do it is to use Visual Studio Installer.

Start Visual Studio Installer and locate your Visual Studio Version, and click on Modify.

And click on Individual components. Than select the .net framework that you need to install.

[image]

Comment: Now we have new error `CreateInstance failed for package [Task Scheduler Package](null)` https://rentry.co/qv3hk#L-1-215

Comment: Can you at all create empty project base on .net framework 4.6.2 and compile it with out issues

Comment: I can't open visual studio at all. When I open it, it shows splash and then immediately closes.

Comment: try to uninstall it  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2017 and install it again, from here https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/ you chose 2017. and install what ever you need of components as shown in the answer, remember to restart your device after uninstalling vs2017,

Comment: I did this before but not works. I also installed VS2019 and have same issue.

Comment: did visual studio worked on your computer previously? if yes, when this problem started, your issues is not .net framework 4.6.2, it must something else. One way is to track back when visual studio was working with out issues and find out what happened after. maybe you installed a software that give issues, maybe you have hardware limitation issue, could be a lot of things. try to create another local user with administrative privilege, login to it and start visual studio from there maybe it is a user profile issue. if all that does not help I guess your issue is far a way from the question

Comment: One other dirty way of fixing it, is make a fresh copy of windows 8.1/10 installation and start every thing over, that said make backup, and make a list of your software before going that direction. but that said try to close all possible reasons before you do this.

Comment: one last thing, check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements you need to have windows  8.1 updated with 2919355 or perhaps if you using windows 10 check if it is updated and have the minimum requirement.

Comment: Yes this problem was in win8.1 as I migrated from win7. Now I am using windows 10 so it get resolved.

Comment: Let me know  if I can added more